# Count bytes in a field

Tags: shell, awk, wc

I have a file that looks like this:

```
ASDFGHJ|ASDFEW|ASFEWFEWAFEWASDFWE FEWFDWAEWA FEWDWDFEW|EWFEW|ASKOKJE
IOJIKNH|ASFDFEFW|ASKDFJEO JEWIOFJS IEWOFJEO SJFIEWOF WE|WEFEW|ASFEWAS
```

I'm having trouble with this file because it's written in Cyrillic and the database complains about number of bytes (vs number of characters). I want to check if, for example, the first field is larger than 10 bytes, the second field is larger than 30 bytes, etc.

I've been trying a lot of different things: awc, wc... I know with wc -c I can count bytes but how can I retrieve only the lines that have a field that is larger than X?

Any idea?

Comment: What's the encoding of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to using `perl` then this could help. I have added comments to make it easier for you to follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use bytes;

## Change the file to path where your file is located
open my $data, '<', 'file';    

## Define an array with acceptable sizes for each fields
my @size = qw( 10 30 ... );        

LINE: while(<$data>) {         ## Read one line at a time      
    chomp;                     ## Remove the newline from each line read

    ## Split the line on | and store each fields in an array
    my @fields = split /\|/;   

    for ( 0 .. $#fields ) {    ## Iterate over the array

        ## If the size is less than desired size move to next line
        next LINE unless bytes::length($fields[$_]) > $size[$_];  
    }

    ## If all sizes matched  print the line
    print "$_\n";  
}
```

Comment: I made a [Perl one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25292383/2088135) that's pretty similar to this.

Comment: @TomFenech I was very inclined to do a one-liner as well, but thought since OP hasn't even tagged `perl` a script will make him open to embrace the solution. Nice job on the one-liner. ^^

Comment: +1 for a clear answer and thanks for your help with my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Perl one-liner that prints the whole line if the field in bytes is longer than the respective member in an array `@m`:

```
perl -F'\|' -Mbytes -lane '@m=(10,10,30,10); print if grep { bytes::length $_ > shift @m } @F' file
```

As the name suggests, `bytes::length` ignores the encoding and returns the length of each field in bytes. The `-a` switch to Perl enables auto-split mode, which creates an array `@F` containing all the fields. I've used the pipe `|` as the delimiter (it needs escaping with a backslash). The `-l` switch removes the newline from the end of the line, ensuring that your final field is the correct length.

The `-n` switch tells Perl to loop through each line in the file. `grep` filters the array `@F` on the condition in the block. I'm using `shift` to remove and return the first element of `@m`, so that each field in `@F` is being compared with the respective element in `@m`. The filtered list will evaluate to true in this context if it contains any elements (i.e. if any of the fields were longer than their limit).

Comment: Since we are not chomping the new line that will most likely get considered in the last field byte compare. Using `-l` option will probably resolve that.

Comment: @jaypal good point about the newline. The `-l` switch doesn't seem to work but I did some tests and it seems the best way to consume the newline is to add it to the list of field separators. `perl -F'[|\n]' -ane 'print $F[$#F]'` works.

Comment: Hmm, thats odd. `-l` option should chomp the newline and put it back during print atleast thats what it was meant for. `:)`

Comment: Ah, I forgot that it also added newlines. That would explain why my "tests" were not working! Thanks, will edit.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the number of bytes in a certain `FIELD` on a certain `LINE` you can issue the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F'|' -v LINE=1 -v FIELD=3 'NR==LINE{print $FIELD}' input.txt | wc -c
```

To print the number of bytes for every field you may use a little loop:

```
awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)print $i}' a.txt | \
while read field ; do 
    nb=$(wc -c <<<"$field")
    echo "$field $nb"

    # Check if the field is too long
    if [ "$nb" -gt 40 ] ; then
        echo "field $field is too long"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: That's pretty good! Do you know how could I have it loop through the entire file? I basically need to check that no field exceeds a number of bytes.

Comment: Depending on your locale and the encoding of the input, `wc -c` counts characters, not bytes. With `LC_ALL=C` it's forced to be the same thing, but without that fix, I don't think this answer is correct.

Comment: @tripleee Where do you have this information from? I have `LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8`.. `wc -c <<<'ö'` outputs `3` (as expected)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix) agrees with you, and indicates `-c` specifically does a byte count (`-m` is character count). Sorry for bringing confusion.

Comment: No worries, I appreciated your feedback. Next time you'll be right again and then I've learned something...